# Curly braces in Scala method call

Tags: scala

In Scala, we can have:

> println { "Hello, world!" }

And from the book 'Programming in Scala':

> The purpose of this ability to substitute curly braces for parentheses for
>   passing in one argument is to enable client programmers to write function
>   literals between curly braces. This can make a method call feel more like a
>   control abstraction.

What does this statement mean?

Comment: Posted here too:https://users.scala-lang.org/t/curly-braces-in-scala-method-call/2588

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is syntactic sugar just for look and feel. When a function takes a function as argument like in

```
def doWith[A, B](todo: A => B): B = ???
```

You would normally have to call it like

```
doWith( input => ... )
// or even
doWith({ input => ... })
```

In scala it is allowed to replace parenthesis with with curlies, so

```
doWith { input =>
  ...
}
```

Has the look and feel of a control structure like

```
if (...) {
  ...
}
```

Imho, that makes calling higher order functions like 'map' or 'collect' much more readable:

```
someCollection.map { elem =>
  ...
  ...
}
```

which is essentially the same as

```
someCollection.map({ elem =>
  ...
  ...
})
```

with less chars.

Comment: Note also that semicolon inference happens between `{` and `}` but not `(` and `)`.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with a `val` instead of a `def`? https://stackoverflow.com/q/56866965/14955

Comment: @Thilo Answered there.

Answer (score 3):

"Control abstractions" are e.g. `if`, `while`, etc. So you can write a function

```
def myIf[A](cond: Boolean)(ifTrue: => A)(ifFalse: => A): A = 
    if (cond) ifTrue else ifFalse
```

(if you aren't familiar with `: => Type` syntax, search for "by-name parameters") you can call it as

```
val absX = myIf(x < 0) { -x } { x }
```

and it looks very similar to normal `if` calls. Of course, this is much more useful when the function you write is more different from the existing control structures.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to (regular) functions and by-name arguments, braces also help with partial functions:

```
processList(l) {
  case Nil => ...
  case h :: t => ...
}
```

and sequences of expressions:

```
doSomething {
  thing1;
  thing2
}
```

Note that `(thing1; thing2)` is not a valid expression in Scala like it would be in, say, ML.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between curly braces `{}` and parenthesis `()` is that you can write multiple lines in the curly braces, while in parenthesis you cannot write more than one line for example.

```
val x :[List[Int]]=List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
x.map(y=> y*5) //it will work fine
x.map(y=> 
case temp:Int=>println(temp)
case _ => println(“NOT Int”)) //it will not work

x.map{y=> 
case temp:Int=>println(temp)
case _ => println(“NOT Int”)} //it willwork
```

So we can say it’s just the synthetic sugar to allow developer to write more then none line without ;  that’s it it may have some other reason too.