# Functions / methods in Scala. How does this work?

Tags: scala, function, akka-http

I am new to Scala and have a hard time understanding all the ways of declaring and using functions. Can someone please explain, step by step, what is going on here?

I am following a course that introduces Akka HTTP. The code works, but I do not understand the route method:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._

def route = path("hello") {
    get {
      complete("Hello, World!")
    }
  }
```

We are defining a method `route` that is being declared the value of `path` (imported from the line above), but then inside the `path` function we have something called `get` that I don't understand.

And when I am declaring `path` as a method, am I overriding it, or what's going on?

I would love if someone can explain what is going on, line by line. And don't mind that it is Akka involved. I want to know about the Scala syntax.

=================================================================

Thanks for all the great answers. I think I get it!

So to summarize my version of it.

`path()` is a function that wants a string. It returns another function that wants a `Directive`. And in Scala lingo we can do some kind of currying to directly send a directive to the returned function.

So everything in the block {} is sent to the function that `path()` returns. And since a block in Scala always returns the last line we are returning the `get` which by the same principles we call with `complete`.

`get` is also a function, that takes one parameter and that can be written as a block. This is equivalent to just writing `get(complete("Hello, world"))`.

Thanks again!

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You ask about declaring functions, but you don't declare any functions in the example you posted.

Answer (score 41):

You don't necessarily need to understand everything in this answer to use akka-http effectively, but I guarantee you there will be times—probably sooner rather than later—that you will be fighting with the compiler and will just want all of the fancy syntactic sugar to go away, and the good news is that there are tools that make this possible (the bad news is that once you get rid of the fancy syntax the reality can be a terrifying mess).

The first thing to note is that while the curly braces here may look a lot like scope or definition delimiters from Java or other languages, they're really just applying methods to arguments. You can do the same thing with parentheses:

```
scala> import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._

scala> val route = path("hello")(get(complete("Hello, World!")))
route: akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route = ...
```

And while these `get` and `complete` things may look like keywords or something, they're really just static methods on `Directives` (approximately—read this whole thing for the full story), so the following is also equivalent:

```
scala> import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives

scala> val route = Directives.path("hello")(
     |   Directives.get(Directives.complete("Hello, World!"))
     | )
route: akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route = ...
```

That hopefully explains some of the syntax, but there's still a lot of invisible stuff going on here. If you're in a REPL, you can use scala-reflect's `reify` as an extremely helpful tool to help make this stuff visible.

To start with a simple (unrelated) example, you might wonder what's happening when you see Scala code like `"a" * 3`, especially if you know that Java strings don't have an `*` operator, so you open a REPL:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.reify
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.reify

scala> reify("a" * 3).tree
res6: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree = Predef.augmentString("a").$times(3)
```

And there's the desugared version, showing the implicit method that's being applied to the string to give it the `*` operator.

In your case you could write something like this:

```
scala> import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._

scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.reify
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.reify

scala> reify(path("hello")(get(complete("Hello, World!")))).tree
res0: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree = Directive.addByNameNullaryApply(Directives.path(Directives._segmentStringToPathMatcher("hello"))).apply(Directive.addByNameNullaryApply(Directives.get).apply(Directives.complete(ToResponseMarshallable.apply("Hello, World!")(Marshaller.liftMarshaller(Marshaller.StringMarshaller)))))
```

We can reformat the reified expression for readability:

```
Directive.addByNameNullaryApply(
  Directives.path(
    Directives._segmentStringToPathMatcher("hello")
  )
).apply(
  Directive.addByNameNullaryApply(Directives.get).apply(
    Directives.complete(
      ToResponseMarshallable.apply("Hello, World!")(
        Marshaller.liftMarshaller(Marshaller.StringMarshaller)
      )
    )
  )
)
```

If you add a couple of imports, this is also perfectly legal Scala code:

```
scala> import akka.http.scaladsl.server.{ Directive, Directives }
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.{Directive, Directives}

scala> import akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.{ Marshaller, ToResponseMarshaller }
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.{Marshaller, ToResponseMarshaller}

scala> val route = Directive.addByNameNullaryApply(
     |   Directives.path(
     |     Directives._segmentStringToPathMatcher("hello")
     |   )
     | ).apply(
     |   Directive.addByNameNullaryApply(Directives.get).apply(
     |     Directives.complete(
     |       ToResponseMarshallable.apply("Hello, World!")(
     |         Marshaller.liftMarshaller(Marshaller.StringMarshaller)
     |       )
     |     )
     |   )
     | )
route: akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route = ...
```

To explain this step by step, we can start with `path("hello")`. We can see from [the API docs](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.1.7/akka/http/scaladsl/server/Directives$.html#path[L](pm:akka.http.scaladsl.server.PathMatcher[L]):akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive[L]) that `Directives.path` doesn't take a string, but rather a `PathMatcher`, so we know that an implicit conversion from `String` to `PathMatcher` is kicking in, and in our fully desugared version, we can see that here:

```
  Directives.path(
    Directives._segmentStringToPathMatcher("hello")
  )
```

And sure enough if we check the docs, `_segmentStringToPathMatcher` is an implicit conversion of the appropriate type.

A similar thing is happening in `complete("Hello, World!")`. `Directives.complete` takes a `ToMarshallableResponse`, not a `String`, so there must be an implicit conversion kicking in. In this case it's `ToResponseMarshallable.apply`, which also requires an implicit `Marshaller` instance, which in this case it gets via an implicit conversion from a `ToEntityMarshaller` to a `ToResponseMarshallable`, where the `ToEntityMarshaller` instance is `Marshaller.StringMarshaller`, and the converter is the `Marshaller.liftMarshaller` part:

```
    Directives.complete(
      ToResponseMarshallable.apply("Hello, World!")(
        Marshaller.liftMarshaller(Marshaller.StringMarshaller)
      )
    )
```

Remember how above I said `get` was just a static method on `Directives`? That was kind of a lie, in the sense that while it is a static method on `Directives`, we're not calling it when we write `get(...)`. Instead this `get` is actually a no-argument method that returns a `Directive0`. `Directive0` is a type alias for `Directive[Unit]`, and while `Directive[Unit]` doesn't have an `apply` method, it can be implicitly converted into a thing that does, via the `addByNameNullaryApply` method on `Directive`. So when you write `get(...)`, Scala desugars that to `get.apply(...)` and then converts the `get` value into a `Route => Route` function, which has an appropriate `apply` method. And exactly the same thing is happening with the `path("hello")(...)` part.

This kind of thing may seem like a nightmare, and as a long-time Scala user I can tell you that it definitely often is. Tools like `reify` and API docs can make it a little less horrible, though.

Answer (score 3):

In your snippets there are several features of the Scala language and the compiler, let's analyse the ones I know:

```
def route = ...
```

defines a functions with no arguments and with result type determined by the return value of its body.

```
path("hello") {
  ...
}
```

I'm not familiar with the `path` function itself but it seems as if there are three things going on in that snippet:

- [Currying](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/currying.html): it's kinda "grouping arguments together";
- [Curly braces instead of round braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706714/curly-braces-in-scala-method-call): to give a different look-and-feel to the call;
- [by-name parameters](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html): to pass a code that will be evaluated only when needed.

I don't want to spend time describing all of them as internet is full of resources that explain them greatly. But I want to link at least [this great introductory article](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/fp-book/how-to-write-functions-multiple-parameter-groups) that helped me a lot in my early days.

The linked article shows you a full example on how to use all three features to build your own control structure like the one of the code you're using.

Moving on, the bit

```
get {
  ...  
}
```

is again an application of the above points but this time there isn't currying so the curly braces are the only argument to the function.

```
complete("Hello, World!")
```

Is just a plain old function call.

**In short** that code uses some "tricks" that transform a function call into sometehing that resembles a special language construct and this can create confusion for the beginners.

This tecnique is used frequently to write Domani-Specific Languages (DSL) in Scala.

---

Answer (score 2):

There are many things that are going on here and this is a pretty complex example to understand scala. But i'll try.

The `route`'s type is `Route`, which is a type alias defined as `type Route = RequestContext ⇒ Future[RouteResult]` where `RequestContext ⇒ Future[RouteResult]` is a function that consumes `RequestContext` and produces `Future[RouteResult]`.

`path` is a method that creates a `Directive[Unit]`. There is an implicit conversion that converts `Directive[Unit]` into a function `Route => Route` (simplified). A function can be called by method `apply` or with compiler sugar as `(???)` or `{???}`.

`get` is a method that creates a `Directive[Unit]` too and similar approach applies to it.

`complete` is of type `StandardRoute` that extends `Route`.

Knowing all this, we could uglify your example that will be written as

```
path("hello").apply { ctx =>
    val inner: Route = { ctx =>
      ctx.complete("done")
    }
    get.apply(inner).apply(ctx)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It might help if you see the code snippet like this:

import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._

```
def route: Route = path("hello") {
    get {
      complete("Hello, World!")
    }
  }
```

I added the `Route` type to show you that you are simply building a route using a syntax provided by Akka HTTP that allows you to define common matching criteria at a higher level, and nest specific criteria inside that section. Here you are using the routing DSL functionality in Akka HTTP. The routing DSL brings some implicits into scope. Using the path method ensures that you are able to handle requests coming into the host for the path `host/hello`, which means your host can now handle get request for the path `/hello`. The code body inside of the path directive represents additional matching criteria to check when we have a proper path match. The complete method knows how to convert to `HttpResponse`. Here you are completing with "hello world", a plain text.

You might have additional HTTP methods standard requests like post, put, delete, as the case may be. Or even custom HTTP methods.

This is a convenient DSL for handling HTTP requests in Akka-HTTP. Check the Akka-HTTP doc [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/index.html)