# Is there a way to call a function defined using `val` in Scala with the whole curly brace block as an argument and not the final result of that block?

Tags: scala, function, user-defined-functions

I know that if we want to pass a block of code in curly braces as an argument to functions defined using `def`, we can write:

```scala
def run(func: => Unit) {
   func
}
run {
    print(1)
    println(2)
} // prints 12
```

But is there a way to achieve the same style with an anonymous function?
I have tried the following:

```scala
val v: (()=>Unit) => Unit = ( w: ()=> Unit) => { w() }
v( () => { println(1); println(2) } ) // Works as expected. Prints 12
v { println(1); println(2) } // error: type mismatch
```

**Correction:**

`()=>Unit` doesn't translate to a function that has a by-name parameter which would allow it to accept code enclosed by curly braces as a parameter. So my question's second part was incorrect.

Alexey Romanov's answer works perfectly if we don't re-specify the argument type in function literal, but if we re-specify the argument type in the function literal which matches the type of variable exactly, it is seen as an error.
For example, if we write

```scala
val v: (=>Unit) => Unit = (w) => { println(0); w } // works
val v: (=>Unit) => Unit = (w:=>Unit) => { println(0); w } // error

val v: (Int => Int) = (w) => 43   // works
val v: (Int => Int) = (w:Int) => 43  // works as well
```

Comment: Not a complete duplicate of the By-name thing, because there `xxx` is still `def xxx` not `val xxx`.

Comment: @Thilo `val fun: (Boolean, => Int) => Int = ...` is the answer. `xxx` is a `def` to make it generic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
val v: (=>Unit) => Unit = w => { println(0); w }

v { println(1); println(2) }
```

`println(0)` inserted purely so you can see this is really a by-name parameter: `0` is printed before `1` and `2`.

Comment: Could you please explain why if we don't re-specify the by-name argument type it works, but if we re-specify the by-name argument type in the function literal which matches the val type exactly, it is seen as an error?

Comment: @black.swordsman It follows the specification (https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/): the type of the parameter in a function literal is a `Type`, the type on the left hand of a `FunctionType` is a `ParamType`. And `=> Unit` is a `ParamType` but not a `Type`. I don't know why a `ParamType` isn't allowed in the literal, but I don't think there is a deep reason. You could ask at https://users.scala-lang.org/.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `block :=> Type` is called `by-name` parameter and does not have to be a function but can be any block of code that evaluated to the type `Type`. That's why the first example works.

The second part does not work because the passed argument:

```
println(1); println(2)
```

evaluates to `Unit` and does not match the expected type `()=>Unit`.

Comment: But in the example with the `def` it *does* work: The block `{ println(1); println(2);}` is magically transformed into a `=> Unit`.