# Strange definition and call of a function with curly bracket in Scala (function as parameter of a function)

Tags: scala

I'm totally new with Scala, I have to maintain an old code, so I have to understand what it does.

Now I am stuck on this piece of code, it is about defining and calling a method.

This is the definition of the method:

```
private def myMethod[I, O](price: Long, id: Int)(i: I)(f: (I, String) => O): O = {
      ..some code..
}
```

this is the method call

```
myMethod(price, id)(b) {
      ..some code.. //single line of code, just calling an other function 
}
```

I understood the part of having type parameter also of having multiple parameter (currying).

But what I didn't understand, is :

- first of all this part: `(f: (I, String) => O)` , this is completely strange for me
- second, why in the method call, it contains code after the `{` symbol, is it overriding the original method? even it's the case, it make no sense to override it when making the call
- also, `myMethod` is supposed to return a value of type `O` , but in my code it's never affected to any variable. (**EDIT:** **this point is clear now, I just misunderstood the code, nvm mind about it**)

Please can any one clarify this points (especially the first and second one which are making me so confused)

---

**EDIT**

```
private var x : classX

myMethod(price, id)(b) {
      x.listX //calling method without parameters
}
```

---

```
def listX (param1: ListFaFBI, param2: String): ListX ={
  //returning an Object of type ListX, not a function
}
```

as you can see that `myMethod` is calling `listX`. if I understood well, `myMethod` is returning the method `listX` itself which has two parameters `ListFaFBI` (or `I`) and `String` and returning `ListX` (or `O`) as defined in `(f: (I, String) => O)`

Comment: `(I, String) => O)` this asks for a function. `{ ... some code ... }` passes the function, in Scala we can omit the parenthesis when calling a method with a single argument. Maybe in your case, the `O` is inferred to **Unit** thus no need to assign the result, or maybe the function is just called by their side-effects. Anyways, this is just basic syntax any tutorial should have covered, if you are going to maintain some code, it would be good to study a little bit more.

Comment: @Bashir that single line of code you say is inside the curly braces - what function does it call and what is the return type of that function? I think it might be a higher order function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `f` is a function that takes in an `I` and a `String` and returns an `O`. `f: (I, String) => O` is syntactic sugar for `f: Function2[I, String, O]`.
2. The braces act essentially the same as parentheses would, although there are some differences, as they can be treated as blocks (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386127/what-is-the-formal-difference-in-scala-between-braces-and-parentheses-and-when)). The code inside the braces is actually a function literal, and it will be passed as `f`. Also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706714/curly-braces-in-scala-method-call). Here,

```
myMethod(price, id)(b) { (i, s) =>
      ..some code.. 
}
```

would be syntactic sugar for

```
myMethod(price, id)(b)({ (i, s) =>
      ..some code.. 
})
```

3. I'm not sure what you mean by "in my code it's never affected to any variable", but I assume that what is returned is either irrelevant or that there is an implied return (in case the call to `myMethod` is at the end of a block.

Comment: hmm nice, I understand now, but if the method f takes  an `I` and a `String` as parameter, why I have directly braces and the code of the method, where are this parameters, I mean the `I` and the `String`?

Comment: @Bashir Can you show me what "...some code..." really is? Is it just an expression or does it have something like `(i, s) => `?

Comment: @Bashir after the braces there should be something like `{ foo =>` or `{ case (i, str) =>` or `{ _.foo` if not, then it seems like a syntax error, but maybe there is an implicit conversion happening, without seeing actual code is hard to help.

Comment: @Bashir It's possible that the function looks like an expression because it uses underscores, like `{ _ + _}`

Comment: @user please reject my edit for your answer, it was a mistake from me

Comment: I edited my answer to mention that in the some code, it is just calling an other function in a single line of code

Comment: @Bashir maybe that method also returns a function?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yeah, that's what I thought too. Might be another curried function

Comment: no it returns an object, I'm sorry guys now it's the weekend, I'm at home and I don't have the code right now, but I assure you that it returns an object

Comment: @Bashir Is it at all possible the object has an `apply` method that takes 2 arguments? If not, that code probably shouldn't work

Comment: I edited the question, I added what is being called inside myMethod , as you see it is calling an other function which returning an Object, not a function that takes 2 arguments. the code is working in prod years ago, so it works, but is's confusing me more and more ..

Answer (score 3):

> first of all this part: (f: (I, String) => O) , this is completely strange for me

It is a *function*, taking a tuple of two elements of type `I` and `String`, and returns an `O`

> why in the method call, it contains code after the { symbol, is it overriding the original method?

Your method is using multiple parameter list, and the syntax of the last parameter group is a block definition that allows to define the function value `((I, String) => O)`

For example, if we had a method which takes a function in the same parameter list:

```
def foo(s: String, f: String => String)
```

Our implementation would look like this:

```
foo("hello", {
    s => s + "world"
  }
)
```

However, if we used a separate parameter group:

```
def foo(s: String)(f: String => String)
```

Our implementation look like this:

```
foo("hello") {
   s => s + "world"
}
```

Which is more eye pleasing and reads nicer.

> myMethod is supposed to return a value of type O , but in my code it's never affected to any variable

If you add the implemention of the method we can better help show you where it is returning a value of type `O`